# post method goes empty in nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, body-parser

I'm trying to get the values from some fields of an index HTML but the post method send me back empty values. It returns this { }, with no values inside of email,nick,name and pass.

this is my server.js code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var app=express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/myDB");


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


app.use(express.static("public"));

app.post("/",function(solicitud,respuesta){
console.log(solicitud.body);
});


app.listen(8080);
```

and here is the HTML form code:

```
                            <div class="col-md-5 center-block no float top-pace text-left">
                            <form method="post" action="/" style="margin-top:1.5em;">
                                <!--EMAIL   -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="anonymous@email.com" required autofocus/>
                                </div>
                                <!--NICK    -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nick" placeholder="Enter your nickname">
                                </div>
                                <!--NAME    -->
                                <div class= "form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Enter your name">
                                </div>
                                <!--PASS    -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" placeholder="***************">
                                </div>

                                <!--BOTON   -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick= "alerta()">Sign Up </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

May the url of the app.post is bad? the form is located in the index.html

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input elements must have *name* attribute.

```
<input type="text" name="nick">
```